# SMBus: Is 100 kHz clock a risky frequency?

Tags: pic, i2c, smbus

I will communicate with a device via SMBus. I use PIC18F26K83 for this. In SMBus spec it says clock minimum clock frequency is 10 kHz and maximum clock frequency is 100 kHz. Would it be a risk to use 100 kHz clock frequency since it is the boundary and max limit? Or is it safer to go with 75 kHz for example?

I will be using multiplexer and communicating with 3 smart batteries. Reading their SOC and send these data with UART to another PIC. Cable length from batteries to PIC will not be more than 1 meter long. I am planning to make MCU clock also 100 kHz.

Comment: Operating at \$100\:\text{kHz}\$ is usually okay. Of course, details matter. But generally, it's not risky. We'd need more details about the context and specific details to offer more, I think.

Comment: Okay so I will be using multiplexer and communicating with 3 smart batteries. Reading their SOC and send these data with UART to another PIC. Cable length from batteries to PIC will not be more than 1 meter long. I am planning to make MCU clock also 100 kHz.

Comment: Cable capacitance is a considerable issue with I2C, SMBus, etc.. If you are connecting the devices with a 1m long cable you should mention that on your question and not on the comments..

Comment: from my understanding, generally 100KHz is defacto standard for **most** i2c chips and it would work with it without problems (or actually designed to work with it)?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the [Wikipedia page about SMBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus) I read that:

> SMBus is derived from I²C

and

> SMBus clock is **defined** from 10–100 kHz while I²C can be 0–100 kHz, 0–400 kHz, 0–1 MHz and 0–3.4 MHz, depending on the mode.

So it is simply a matter of **definition** that the SMBus clock should be 10 to 100 kHz.

It does not mean that a 1 Hz SMBus would not work. If you made your SMBus circuit such that it would work at 1 Hz, then it would. But then it does not meet the official SMBus specification so it would not be correct to call it an SMBus. But like I²C, it can work.